# "as" Versus "is" With a Cast

Tags: c#, performance, casting

I frequently find myself needing to `switch` types. I know this has lots of discussion for Roslyn, but since I'm dealing with production code, I just have a standard practice / performance question about the already-present options: `is` and `as`.

Given the classes,

```
abstract class Foo { }
class Bar : Foo { }
class Tada : Foo { }
```

Is there any real difference between the following patterns?

```
Foo toUse = ...;

if (toUse != null)
{
    Bar barInstance = toUse as Bar;

    if (barInstance != null)
    {
        // use barInstance
    }
    else
    {
        Tada tadaInstance = toUse as Tada;

        if (tadaInstance != null)
        {
            // use tadaInstance
        }
        else
        {
            // Check whatever other types there are, or throw a NotImplementedException
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // handle the null case
}
```

As compared to

```
Foo toUse = ...;

if (toUse != null)
{
    Bar barInstance = toUse as Bar;

    if (toUse is Bar)
    {
        Bar barInstance = (Bar)toUse;

        // use barInstance
    }
    else if (toUse is Tada)
    {
        Tada tadaInstance = (Tada)toUse;

        // use tadaInstance
    }
    else
    {
        // Check whatever other types there are, or throw a NotImplementedException
    }
}
else
{
    // handle the null value
}
```

Clearly, typos permitting, these two have the same impact. They *should* do exactly the same thing. But are there performance concerns here? I've always kind of appreciated the single-operation nature of the first pattern, but it's so messy. Not to mention, it leaves everything in scope so you wind up with that much messier a setup the more cases you include.

Is `as` really just a syntactic shortcut for this?

```
if (value is type)
    return (type)value;
else
    return null;
```

Or does it differ in the way the compiler reads it?

**Edit**

Just to be perfectly clear, since there was understandable and reasonable concern here, I'm not writing code that needs to depend on performance this heavily. This is just a theoretical curiosity. Not to mention, I'd much rather be aware of the performance sacrifice I'm making for readability than do it blindly, even though I'll take it every time.

Comment: Grab ILSpy and look at the generated IL. There's your answer.

Comment: There's an FxCop warning about this. What hints does it give?

Comment: if performance of as or is becomes critical you should clearly rework design and remove some classes

Comment: The two ways are not the same, you check if `toUse as Bar` is `null` which can have two reasons: 1. the type is incompatible 2. the object was already `null`. The `is` checks first and only if the type is compatible.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub yes, I agree completely. It was more of just a curiosity based on the principle of the matter and how the IL interprets each. I wouldn't depend on those checks in a situation where performance matters that much.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If the object was `null`, the `is` check would fail (return `false`) too. That is, if `toUse is Bar` can return `false` if `toUse` is `null` _or_ `toUse` is not a `Bar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `as` is technically more performant than `is` plus a cast.  There are fewer total operations that occur.

For practical purposes, the difference in speed is almost never measurable in the real world, so using the more maintainable/readable version in your case will be better.

However, large checks against type is typically a sign of a design problem.  You may want to consider rethinking your design to prevent the checks entirely.  Generics or virtual method calls can typically eliminate the need for this type of check entirely.

Comment: I think the only code I have in production that uses `as` is when I read a value from ASP.Net Session.  I don't think I've ever used `is`.

Comment: Fair enough. Yeah, I wouldn't do a lot of checks like that--the performance really doesn't matter in my cases. In this particular one, I even do `Task.Delay`s to slow down some of the work. It was more of just a curiosity based on principle. I'd definitely go with the more readable option in practice. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One more thing to point out is that when you do like below

```
Bar barInstance = toUse as Bar;
```

It's always recommended to check for nullity before using the `barInstance` likewise you are doing.

```
if (barInstance != null)
{
    // use barInstance
}
```

Cause in case of direct cast like `(Bar)toUse` if the cast fails you will get the right exception details whereas if you say `toUse as Bar` and don't check for nullity you will subside the original exception and end up facing a `Nullreference` exception.

Comment: I would say that your sample may change semantics by ignoring incompatible types. Of course it is better to get the right exception instead of `NullReferenceException`. But `NullReferenceException` might be better than swallowing errors.

Comment: @AlexD, I don't agree on `But NullReferenceException might be better than swallowing errors` cause I don't mean swallowing the error rather catch them if they surface.

Comment: I meant the following. Let's assume that it is a logical error if `toUse` is not `Bar`. Using `(Bar)toUse` would lead to the right exception. Using just `toUse as Bar` would lead to a wrong exception, but at least it would be an exception. Using `if (barInstance != null) {}`, without `else`, would hide the logical error by doing nothing.